# Any way to send Gmail Out of Office/Auto-reply at the same times every week?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, automation

Because my clients bother me out of hours I would like to have my Out of Office respond out of hours without having to set it manually every day.

To comlicate matters further I want to send one message on between Friday 5pm and Monday 9am and a different message out of hours on all other weekdays.

How do I do that?

I am no coder, so do I just duplicate and adjust the IF statement (apologies if this is the wrong terminology) and adjust to suit?

Also, would I be correct in thinking that this sends a plain text response? I would like to send an HTML response so that it will display corporate logos etc. like a standard email reply.

Comment: To get images in the email footer I have been looking at the documentation Google provide but I am thinking about changing the last line of the IF statement to something like this: <code>for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { threads[i].reply(wkdaypmMessage,{htmlBody: "some text<BR><BR><img src="cid:imageKey" />", inlineImages: <img src="cid:imageKey" />});</code> My issue is that I can't understand how to implement it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replybody-options

Comment: Self-answered questions are allowed, and _encouraged_, but the question post should contain just the question and you should add an actual answer post with your solution. See also: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have seen other questions were the OP was criticised for not updating the question when self-answered. Perhaps that person was wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer to my own question.

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var wkend = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
  var wkendMessage = "Hi, Thank you for contacting us. The office is now closed. All emails will be attended to when the office re-opens at 9:00am on Monday morning.";
  var wkdayMessage = "Hi, Thank you for contacting us. The office is now closed. All emails will be attended to when the office re-opens in the morning.";
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if (wkend.indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 5 && hour >= 17)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkendMessage);
    }
  }
  else if (hour < 9 || hour >= 17) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkdayMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

**I still need help to format the output so that there are images in the footer though :)**

Comment: Should I post a new question about how to get inline images in the footer of the output using this script? Unsure of the etiquette here

Comment: Yes, you should post a new question. This isn't a discussion forum.